# What is this plant

Tags: identification

This plant only flowers when there is no leaf, when flowers die back the leaves then appear, would appreciated any ideas as to what it is.

[image]

Comment: I don't suppose you also have a picture of the leaves? Or can you describe them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like Haemanthus coccineus, a member of the family Amaryllidaceae native to southern Africa.

http://pza.sanbi.org/haemanthus-coccineus

http://www.strangewonderfulthings.com/254.htm

Comment: Interesting flowers, I would never guessed the family. Could you expand your answer a little bit?

Comment: What an awesome flower, and the name was probably hard to find! I agree with @GiacomoCatenazzi, though, in asking for more details please. Answers relying almost completely on links can be hard because links tend to go down over time. Also additional information right here would be a great help to people, so they wouldn't have to look any further. Thanks!